# How to create a universal getter/mutator for datetimes in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, getter, mutators

I have created one and I thought it works:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Carbon\Carbon;

trait FormatDates
{

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        parent::setAttribute($key, $value);

        if (strtotime($value))
            $this->attributes[$key] = Carbon::parse($value);
    }
}
```

But there is a problem when calling related models. For example if you have an Article and Tag model and you want to get all tags like this:

```
$article->tags
```

it returns `null` because of that getter mutator.

How to fix this?

---

#### update 17.11.2017

I have found a solution to my problem. The best way to present the date in locale is to use this function:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::setToStringFormat("d.m.Y H:i");
```

simply create a service provider or a middleware and it will show all $dates in format you want. There is no need to make a getter.

Comment: `tags` is a relationship right? so running `$article->tags` should return a collection of tags related to the article, right?

Comment: Yes that is right! But it returns null. And if I remove the getter then it returns the collection of tags if they exist of course.

Comment: You want an universal getter/mutator for just the attributes of the given Model ??

Comment: Yes, but so that the related models don't break...I mean stay intact and work properly.

Comment: [read the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: why did you change your code?

Comment: This is my original problem... the code before was from another question on SO. So I am really sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based from this: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_getAttribute

The description says:

> Get a plain attribute (not a relationship).

Luckily there are another two methods below it called **getRelationValue** and **getRelationshipFromMethod**, and it reads:

> Get a relationship.
>
> Get a relationship value from a method.

respectively.

And in your example, it looks like you're calling a relation.

I think you should consider it when doing your universal getter/mutator.

**UPDATE:**

If you inspect the code, the `getAttribute` also calls the `getRelationValue` method. But it is the last resort of the *function*; if the **key** is neither an attribute or has a mutator or is a method of the *class*.

Here is the stub: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L302

```
/**
 * Get an attribute from the model.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAttribute($key)
{
    if (! $key) {
        return;
    }
    // If the attribute exists in the attribute array or has a "get" mutator we will
    // get the attribute's value. Otherwise, we will proceed as if the developers
    // are asking for a relationship's value. This covers both types of values.
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->attributes) ||
        $this->hasGetMutator($key)) {
        return $this->getAttributeValue($key);
    }
    // Here we will determine if the model base class itself contains this given key
    // since we don't want to treat any of those methods as relationships because
    // they are all intended as helper methods and none of these are relations.
    if (method_exists(self::class, $key)) {
        return;
    }
    return $this->getRelationValue($key);
}
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Since you've changed your question:

You can just put the attribute name to `$casts` or `$dates` array (in your **Model**) so Laravel will automatically transform it into a `Carbon` instance when accessing it, like this:

```
class Article extends Model {
    ...
    protected $dates = ['some_date_attribute`];
```

or with `$casts`

```
    ...
    protected $casts = ['some_date_attributes' => 'date'];
```

Comment: maybe I don't even need a getter.... what if I just add the dates in $casts variable array and set them to cast to 'datetime'. I tried now and it works. but need to test it little bit more

Comment: that's what I'm also thinking since you've changed your question :P

Comment: This getter is really f**** up. Too much things going on under the hood

Comment: yes. haha! you have to be extra careful with the framework's extensibility xD

Comment: Man the laravel-recipes.com is down...how is that possible....I need it right now. Because there were all the examples for form input fields....maybe you know some other site with the list of examples for form input fields for Form facade

Comment: im sorry, i don't really use the Form facade :( I stay with the native *html* form creation. maybe you can watch Laracasts and try things yourself. :)

Comment: I have figured something out. There is a function `\Carbon\Carbon::setToStringFormat("d.m.Y H:i");` and now I don't even need getter... can you please change your answer because this is the best solution. This can be added into service provider or middleware and it works great.

Comment: hi, you can just update your question for whatever worked for you. There are many possible solutions to your question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You really can avoid this, it's already there!

on the model Class you can do:

```
protected $dates = ['nameOfTheDateOrTimestampTypeField','nameOfAnotherOne'];
```

Comment: Try to save the date in this format "30.09.2017 10:32" and then tell me why it doesn't work?

Comment: Why you should do that, you just need to store the pure date data, then you decide how to display it in the presentation layer.

Comment: The company uses this bootstrap datetime picker all in one and the date needs to be shown in front end always in german local format "d.m.Y H:i" I am not the one who can decide or change that. I just need to find the solutions to solve the problems. True, it would be much easier for me if I could save only the date, but that is not the case.

Comment: it's ALWAYS better to separate the presentation layer (view) from the stored data (model). https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/why-escape-on-input-is-a-bad-idea/

Comment: You are right about that, but as I have said I am not the one who decides HOW the things are done, I just follow the orders.